# How does C# DynamicObject internally work?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I read about `dynamic` and its contributions to the language. The DLR manages any call to a member of an object (`dynamic`), to do so it uses reflection mechanisms. But I can't understand the behavior of **DyamicObject** type (internally).

When you inherit from **DynamicObject** you get the possibility of creating something like the existing **ExpandoObject**, you need to overwrite **TrySetMember**, **TryGetMember**, and other methods. My question is: when you do **object.method**, how is this passed to the **TryGetMember** of our class, at first sight it seems that **DynamicObject** is bounded to the DLR, but I doubt it.

Comment: Have you tried reading a book or some forum describing dynamic objects? Or at least have you asked Google the same question?

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy i google it but all results where about the functionality, i'm looking for the things behind. Books and materials i have red all explains the capabilities but say nothing about inner implementation.

Comment: I read about it in Jeffrey Richter's book "CLR via C#". It's really a lot to explain and I'm not sure I remember everything - you'd better read that too. Briefly saying it compiles few versions of the code you write with "If" statements checking the dynamic object .GetType() result. If it isn't able to predict the type, it uses reflection.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy thanks i will find that book. I got to the part that uses reflection but this doesn't justify that if i do object.method this transparently translate in a call for TryInvokeMember. An explanation could be that the DLR is instructed to call this method arbitrarily when looking for some non existing method. Is the last is true or false is the answer i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the clarified question in comment.

While I'm not sure, I suppose the TryInvokeMember etc functions just wrappers over reflection to overcome the basic design problem of reflection - it throws only one type of exception: TargetInvocationException. All other exceptions including your own exceptions from the methods you are calling are wrapped with TargetInvocationException.

dynamic variables doesn't have that issue - they throw exactly the same excaption that was thrown originally. While they still use reflection internally in some cases, they should unwrap the underlying exceptions. And I thing this is the purpose of TryInvokeMember and related methods. Also it enabled developers of CLR to handle calls of unexisting members in more appropriate and special way.